# Nan can't wrap and unwrap object with v8::Object field

Tags: node.js, v8

At first I defined it like this(basically the same as the *object wrap* example in the documentation, the only difference is the example wrapped a `double` value property, but mine is an `v8::Object`):

.h:

```
#include <nan.h>

using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo;

class MyObject : public Nan::ObjectWrap {
    public:
    static void Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> module);

    private:
    explicit MyObject(Local<Object>);
    ~MyObject();

    static Nan::Persistent<v8::Function> constructor;
    static void New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info);
    static void GetConfig(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info);

    Local<Object> Config;
};
```

.cc:

```
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;

Nan::Persistent<v8::Function> MyObject::constructor;
MyObject::MyObject(Local<Object> config) : Config(config){}
MyObject::~MyObject(){}

// return an object when required
void MyObject::Init(Local<Object> module)
{
    Nan::HandleScope scope;

    Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> tpl = Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(New);
    tpl->SetClassName(Nan::New("myObject").ToLocalChecked());
    tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);

    // prototypes
    Nan::SetPrototypeMethod(tpl, "getConfig", GetConfig);

    constructor.Reset(tpl->GetFunction());
    module->Set(Nan::New("exports").ToLocalChecked(), tpl->GetFunction());
}

void MyObject::New(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
    Local<Object> conf = info[0].As<Object>();
    MyObject* myObject = new MyObject(conf);
    MyObject->Wrap(info.This());
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(info.This());
}

void MyObject::GetConfig(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info)
{
    MyObject* myObject = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<MyObject>(info.Holder());
    Local<Object> conf = myObject->Config;

    info.GetReturnValue().Set(conf);
}
```

js:

```
var Test = require("./build/Release/test");
var test = new Test({a: 1});
console.log(test.getConfig()); // logs 3276x randomly
```

Seems the `Config` field got garbage collected. If that was the situation, I don't understand why, since `MyObject` instance is clearly still in scope. But still I tried to make `Config` persistent.

Interestingly, directly changing `Config`'s type to `Persistent<Object> *` didn't work either, but when I added these seemed irrelevant lines to test whether I passed the right object from js before the object got wrapped in `MyObject::New()`, it worked:

```
Local<Object> test = Nan::New(*MyObject->Config);
Local<v8::String> v8Str = Nan::To<v8::String> (test->Get(Nan::New("a").ToLocalChecked())).ToLocalChecked();
v8::String::Utf8Value v8StrUtf8(v8Str);
std::string str = std::string(*v8StrUtf8);
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

What's wrong here? What's the right way to wrap a v8::Object? Why those property accessing lines can make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hold onto a value for a longer period of time (beyond the current scope), you need to make the reference a Persistent instead of a Local. Doing so will prevent the value from being garbage collected.

So change your `Config` definition to:

```
Nan::Persistent<Object> Config;
```

I haven't tested it, but you *may* also need to change your constructor to:

```
MyObject::MyObject(Local<Object> config) {
  Config.Reset(config);
}
```

Then when you want to retrieve the value you would need to instead get a Local handle from the Persistent like:

```
Local<Object> conf = Nan::New(myObject->Config);
```

Comment: Thanks mscdex, I tried to make a pointer persistent instead of the value.

Comment: `Global` is the non-deprecated name for the type that allows you to keep stuff around beyond a scope.   Local/Global are what used to be called Handle/Persistent.  At least that's my understanding.